# soapui rest property transfer

Tags: json, rest, xpath, soapui

I'm trying to create a simple Test Step using REST.
I have class Calculator with add & sub API (with PathParams):

```
@Path("add/{x}/{y}")
@Path("sub/{*x*}/{y}")
```

I would like that the output of the add will be the *x* of sub input.

the add REST output is:

```
{add: "addResult"}
```

but I'm getting error for the declare namespace.
I tried:

```
declare namespace nsa='http://'localhost'/REST-TEST/rest/Calculator/add';
//nsa/sum
```

and

```
declare namespace nsa='http://'localhost'/REST-TEST/rest/Calculator/add/{x}/{y}';
//nsa/sum
```

but non works

please help me figure out what to write in the Source and Target to make it happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer for that....

use the namespace nsa as a prefix with :
and for the x and y parameters, keep them as parameters!

as for this

declare namespace nsa='http://'localhost'/REST-TEST/rest/Calculator/add/**$**{x}/**$**{y}';

//nsa**:**sum